# How to implement Azure Monitoring Alert VM Heartbeat with Log Workspace using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, kql, azure-log-analytics

Need to implement a series of Alerts in Azure Monitoring using KQL/Kusto queries. It's very basic e.g. Heartbeat, free disk space (based on the agent output to a Log Workspace).

Looking at the Terraform documentations, I am unsure on which resources to use. I would expect that I would need to build the query in a Resource first and then build the Alert Resource. However, looking at the documentation it seems that the query should be added to this Resource.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_activity_log_alert

Anyways it would be awesome if somebody would share an example of implementing azure monitor alerts for virtual machines, Win/linux.

Comment: Please refer : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_scheduled_query_rules_log & https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [UserP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16279655/userp). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

**azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert**

- Manages an AlertingAction Scheduled Query Rules resource within Azure Monitor.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "monitoring-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "example" {
  name                = "appinsights"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  application_type    = "web"
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "example2" {
  name                = "appinsights2"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  application_type    = "web"
}

# Example: Alerting Action with metric trigger
resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert" "example" {
  name                = format("%s-queryrule", var.prefix)
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  action {
    action_group           = []
    email_subject          = "Email Header"
    custom_webhook_payload = "{}"
  }
  data_source_id = azurerm_application_insights.example.id
  description    = "Query results grouped into AggregatedValue; alert when results cross threshold"
  enabled        = true
  # Count all requests with server error result code grouped into 5-minute bins by HTTP operation
  query       = <<-QUERY
  requests
    | where tolong(resultCode) >= 500
    | summarize AggregatedValue = count() by operation_Name, bin(timestamp, 5m)
QUERY
  severity    = 1
  frequency   = 5
  time_window = 30
  trigger {
    operator  = "GreaterThan"
    threshold = 3
    metric_trigger {
      operator            = "GreaterThan"
      threshold           = 1
      metric_trigger_type = "Total"
      metric_column       = "operation_Name"
    }
  }
}
```

You can refer to [azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert#example-usage) and [Support alerts based on Log analytics queries](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3951)